# How to create code templates in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-templates

If you are programming in C# in Visual Studio and type in "prop" and hit enter, the IDE generates a property. Eclipse also [has this feature](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/eclipse-tip-add-code-template-eclipse/) and the user can define custom commands that expands into custom code. Is this possible in Visual Studio?

Comment: Those are called 'code snippets' and yes, you can create them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to leppie's comment I managed to find the solution on my own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=vs.80).aspx